# If I download the Resurgence pack, will the new weapons be available in single player?

Tags: mass-effect-3, me3-resurgence-pack

The [Resurgence Pack](http://masseffect.wikia.com/wiki/Mass_Effect_3%3a_Resurgence_Pack) is now available in most places for Mass Effect 3.  Included in the pack are three brand new weapons:

- [Kishock Harpoon Gun](http://masseffect.wikia.com/wiki/Kishock_Harpoon_Gun)
- [Striker Assault Rifle](http://masseffect.wikia.com/wiki/Striker_Assault_Rifle)
- [Geth Plasma SMG](http://masseffect.wikia.com/wiki/Geth_Plasma_SMG)

Will these weapons be made available to my Shepard for use in single player?  If so, how?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you can see by clicking on weapon links you can acquire them **only in multiplayer**.

- "Acquisition: Multiplayer: Randomly rewarded by purchasing a
  multiplayer item pack after the Mass Effect 3: Resurgence Pack has
  been downloaded and installed."

From [Mass effect official site](http://masseffect.com/videos/video/83a4f918902bbb6d3868b06b5568d0e8)

- "first **multiplayer expansion**"
- "deadly weapons, new consumables, and powerful characters for each
  class **in multiplayer**"

Comment: You do realize that there isn't anything on the wiki pages that actually says they can't be used in single player, right?  I need something a little more concrete than that.  Lack of proof isn't the same as proof of the negative.

Comment: True,but the answer still stays...if there was a way to obtain the weapons in single player it would be listed there,look at few other weapons all have details where they can be acquired.The other thing is if the DLC items were obtainable in single player most likely you would get ingame e-mail or new mini mission which is not the case here.

Comment: That's fair, but my problem is that your answer is very matter of fact when you can't know for sure just from the wiki pages.

Comment: Well it is pretty hard to prove that something doesn't exist,there is always a chance someone missed it and the developers don't often give much detail to avoid spoilers.Through there are some notable quotes for this case.

Comment: I guess that second part is more definitive.  I would have liked to try them out in single player first though.

Answer (score 2):

I haven't gotten my hands on Resurgence yet.  But if these weapons act in a similar fashion to the Collector Assault Rifle, which is also (supposedly) only available in multiplayer, they should be possible to mod in.

Again using the Collector Rifle as example, I was able to edit coalesced.bin to get my hands on this weapon in single player mode, as far as I can tell it also became available to squad mates in single player.  Simply created a custom key binding that gives the weapon when pressed, once the keybind is used the weapon stays, so its not necessary to re-add it every time.  ME Wiki has lots of info re: coalesced.bin tweaks.

Comment: Yeah, too bad I'm on the 360, not PC.  However, since this could be useful to others, I give you a "Welcome to Gaming.SE" upvote.